# How to exclude specific pages from caching in PWA?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I am using Progressive Web App  on a website that works fine, now I want some pages should not be cached.
the urls that I want should not be cached are saved in a JavaScript variable

```
var cacheExclude = [
    '/user/register',
    '/item/new',
    '/login'
];
```

I want when these pages are accessed offline the '**/offline.html**' should be shown instead.

below is my service worker that handles cache

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {

    //Fetch from network and cache
    var fetchFromNetwork = function(response) {
        var cacheCopy = response.clone();
        if (event.request.headers.get('Accept').indexOf('text/html') != -1) {
            caches.open(version + 'pages').then(function(cache) {
                cache.put(event.request, cacheCopy).then(function() {
                    limitCache(cache, 25);
                })
            });
        } else if (event.request.headers.get('Accept').indexOf('image') != -1) {
            caches.open(version + 'images').then(function(cache) {
                cache.put(event.request, cacheCopy).then(function() {
                    limitCache(cache, 10); 
                });
            });
        } else {
            caches.open(version + 'assets').then(function add(cache) {
                cache.put(event.request, cacheCopy);
            });
        }

        return response;
    }

    //Fetch from network failed
    var fallback = function() {
        if (event.request.headers.get('Accept').indexOf('text/html') != -1) {
            return caches.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
                return response || caches.match('/offline.html');
            })
        } 
    }

    //This service worker won't touch the admin area
    if (event.request.url.match(/admin/)) {
        return;
    }

    //This service worker won't touch non-get requests
    if (event.request.method != 'GET') {
        return;
    }

    //For HTML requests, look for file in network, then cache if network fails.
    if (event.request.headers.get('Accept').indexOf('text/html') != -1) {
                    event.respondWith(fetch(event.request).then(fetchFromNetwork, fallback));
        return;
            }

    //For non-HTML requests, look for file in cache, then network if no cache exists.
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request).then(function(cached) {
            return cached || fetch(event.request).then(fetchFromNetwork, fallback);
        })
    )
});
```

I simply want to redirect to the offline page if any of the cacheExclude paths match?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to exclude some paths, you can use Glob negation:

```
var cacheExclude = [
    '!(*/user/register'),
    '!(*/item/new'),
    '!(*/login')
];
```

Eventually you can skip the * if there won't be anything before the matching glob expression.

However, you can also simply redirect to the offline page if any of the *cacheExclude* paths has a match, hence not needing to negate the Glob expression.

```
var cacheExclude = [
    '/user/register',
    '/item/new',
    '/login'
];

hasUrlCacheExcludeMatch(url) {
  // Note: .endsWith() does not work in IE. 
  return cacheExclude.some(path => url.endsWith(path));
}


self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  if (event.request.method === 'GET' &&
      event.request.headers.get('accept').indexOf('text/html') !== -1) {

      if(hasUrlCacheExcludeMatch(event.request.url)){
        const cachedResponse = await cache.match('/offline.html');
        return cachedResponse;
      }

      // Your other code...
  }
});
```

---

Update for **Opaque Responses**

Opaque Responses always have `STATUS = 0` even when the Response is `OK` and they are not added to the cache via the `add` method of the CACHE API, since these accept codes only in the 200 to 399 range.

If the cache gets updated via the `put` method, you can analyze the response code and if `response.ok === false` you can programmatically take action.

Alternatively, you can use Workbox to implement your caching strategies as it automatically skips caching opaque responses.

Comment: I simply want to redirect to the offline page if any of the cacheExclude paths match, I am not good in Service Worker scripting please tell me how to amended my code?

Comment: I updated my answer with a possible implementation.

Comment: @Francesco I know this is old, but I am trying to not cache a register page and a login page. The problem is that the response from those pages is producing an opaque type and there is no URL in the response to compare with the excluded pages. So they get cached anyways. the URL is "http://localhost/testtracker/register/" I would not think this would cause a cors problem.

Comment: That's strange as opaque responses have status 0 and this is skipped by the CACHE API `add` therefore it should not be cached out of the box. It could be updated via the `put` method, on that case you should programmatically skip it checking the status. See the update response for more details.