# How to prevent caching of specific pages in a PWA straight Javascript

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I am working on localhost building a PWA. There are two pages currently that I do not want to cache. The "register" page and the "login" page. I have set up an array of pages that I do not want to cache and I am trying to run a check for those pages before the pages are cached.

**The Problem**

When I write to the console the request, for every page that is navigated to, the response type is always "opaque" and response.url is always empty. There is NO cross-origin going on.

Here is my fetch event listener:

```
// Fetch the http calls
self.addEventListener('fetch', evt => {

    // Don't cache ajax files or service worker
    if (evt.request.url.match(/AJAX.php/) || evt.request.url.match(/sw.js/)) {
        // console.log("did not cache ajax.php or sw.js")
        return;
    }

    evt.respondWith(
        networkFirst(evt.request, '/testtracker/public/src/libs/fall_back_page.php')
    ); 
})
```

My networkFirst function:

```
const networkFirst = async (request, fallbackURL) => {
    try {
        const netRes = await fetch(request);
         console.log("Network Response: ", netRes);
        if (netRes.ok) {
            // This is where I will check for pages I do not want to cache.
            // But every page that is navigated to shows type: opaque and response.url is empty AND yet it caches the page somehow....
            // If I'm not able to get a reponse.url, I can't filter out the excluded pages.
            // The if statement is just to demonstrate logic flow, it is not the actual expression I would use.
            if(!excludedPage){    
                const cache = await caches.open(dynamicCacheName);
                cache.put(request, netRes.clone());
            }
        }
        return netRes;
    }
    catch (error) {
         console.log("ERROR: ",error);
        // console.log("Fallback URL: ",fallbackURL);

        const fallback = await caches.match(fallbackURL);
        const cachedRes = await caches.match(request);
        return cachedRes || fallback;
    }
}
```

When I click on the link "localhost/testtracker/register/" to the registration page I am getting these fetch requests.

> Network Response URL:
> Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost/testtracker/css/w3.css', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} sw.js:26
> Network Response URL:
> Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost/testtracker/includes/js/main.js', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} sw.js:26
> Network Response URL:
> Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost/testtracker/includes/js/registerJS.js', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} sw.js:26
> Network Response URL:
> Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost/testtracker/includes/js/app.js', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} sw.js:26
> **Network Response URL:**
> **Response {type: 'opaque', url: '', redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …} sw.js:26**
> Network Response URL:
> Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost/testtracker/manifest.webmanifest', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} sw.js:26
> Network Response URL:
> Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} sw.js:26
> Network Response URL:
> Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost/testtracker/siteImages/icon-192x192.png',  redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …} sw.js:26
> Network Response URL:
> Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost/testtracker/register/src/inc/referralsAPI.php', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}

I can only assume that the request I have bolded is the request to the "register" page and there is no URL as it is of type opaque.

But my dynamic page cache caches the registration page:

> 0 /testtracker/css/w3.css                         basic   text/css
> 1 /testtracker/includes/js/app.js                 basic   application/javascript
> 2 /testtracker/includes/js/main.js                basic   application/javascript
> 3 /testtracker/includes/js/registerJS.js          basic   application/javascript
> 4 /testtracker/manifest.webmanifest               basic   text/plain
> **5   /testtracker/register/                          basic   text/html;**
> 6 /testtracker/register/src/inc/referralsAPI.php  basic   text/html;
> 7 /testtracker/siteImages/icon-192x192.png        basic   image/png
> 8 /ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0   cors    application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8 77,160  9/21/2023, 11:42:20 PM  Accept-Encoding

I have been looking up similar issues and I found this: [How to exclude specific pages from caching in PWA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388008/how-to-exclude-specific-pages-from-caching-in-pwa) but the answer did not work for me.

I am new to service workers and caching, so I may be missing something. I would appreciate the help.

**Question**
Why is the request response coming back as opaque and how can I keep the service workers from caching the registration and login pages?